# Sidekiq Client Middleware missing the "after" code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

It appears that the code AFTER the `yield` in my sidekiq client middleware is not executing.  No exception was raised (I'm trapping that), so I can't imagine how the code is being skipped (no return inside the lambda, either).  Can anyone explain why?  Here's the middleware code:

```
class SidekiqClientWorkless
  def initialize(options = nil)
  end
  def call(worker, msg, queue)
    Log.create!(task: "testing", message: "This message gets logged")
    begin
      yield
    rescue Exception => e
      require 'ruby-debug'
      debugger
    end
    Log.create!(task: "testing", message: "This message does not get logged")
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => 'redis://user:pwd@barb.redistogo.com:9725/', 
                :namespace => 'mynamespace' }
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add SidekiqClientWorkless, :foo => 1, :bar => 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ensure` as per the example from the [docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware)?

I'm honestly not sure why it would be required, but it seems to be...